# Why is this probabilistic reasoning invalid?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

A man decides to test if a coin is fair, or biased towards heads. He flips the coin 1000 times, and it comes up heads 500 times. His strategy is as follows. All we have to do is assume the coin is fair, and calculate the probability, under that assumption, that we would have gotten the result we got. If that probability is very low, we conclude that if the coin were fair, this outcome would be exceedingly unlikely, and therefore, the coin is probably not fair.

The man computes the probability of a fair coin coming up heads 500 times, and finds it comes to $3.05\cdot10^{-151}$. So he concludes the coin is biased towards heads.

In the language of statistical tests: he's using a test that consists in concluding the coin is biased iff it comes up with exactly $500$ heads. We've shown that the probability of type 1 error for this test is essentially zero.

Why is this reasoning not valid?

Comment: because it's non zero would be my first thought. Also, more than half of the possibilities, are also as likely or less likely than that ?

Comment: So you have made a hypothesis test? You can argue with the result of it. But it depends how the test was made.

Comment: You have dropped the "measure the probability that data at least as favorable towards the alternative hypothesis as the given data will be seen under the null hypothesis" part. Assuming the alternative hypothesis is the two-sided one, "data at least as favorable toward the alternative hypothesis as the given data" is literally any data, since the measure of favorability is $|X-500|$ where $X$ is the number of heads observed. This "paradox" is even more apparent when dealing with continuous distributions, in which case the probability of observing *anything in particular* is zero.

Comment: (Cont.) In even more bland statistics jargon: a test like this has a probability of type 1 error of basically zero and a probability of type 2 error of basically 1. Statisticians at a cultural level are more concerned about type 2 errors than type 1 errors, which in more colloquial language means they would rather say they don't know than say something false. You can do the reverse, but then you create weird situations like this one where you essentially deny any claim that anyone makes.

Comment: @Ian Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Ian You're mixing up type 1 and 2 - my whole point is that this test has a low probability of a type 1 error, but that's exactly the kind of error we made - we concluded the coin was biased even though it's intuitively more likely to be fair. Yes, the test has a high probability of a type *two* error - concluding the coin is fair when it's not - but I don't think that's what's fundamentally wrong with it, since if you brought up that criticism, surely the man would just say, "Well! Good thing I didn't end up concluding the coin was fair, then! Dodged a bullet, I guess."

Comment: Actually I mixed up type 1 and 2 but across the board: your probability of type 1 error is *high* because whenever the null (i.e. fairness) holds, you reject it. In fact you reject fairness essentially across the board, which means you almost always commit a type 1.

Comment: @Ian No, the opposite - I only conclude the coin is unfair when I get precisely 500 heads. So I almost always conclude the coin is fair. But since, as it happens, I ended concluding unfairness anyway, the criticism that my test is biased towards concluding unfairness doesn't seem relevant. It would be like if I had a test for the cancer/cigarette link so biased that it looked like I was in the pocket of the tobacco industry, and then I concluded cancer causes cigarettes anyway. The high type 2 error probability of my test would if anything *strengthen* my conclusion.

Comment: @JackM I don't even understand the logic in that, then. The basic logic I was following was: assuming fairness, *any* particular outcome, *including* exactly 500 heads, is extremely unlikely, so you always reject the null hypothesis of fairness. Can you carefully clarify how your test works and give some reasoning for why it works that way? (Of course we collectively know this reasoning is faulty but it is instructive to have a devil's advocate position to specifically criticize.)

Comment: Yeah at this point what you're describing makes so little sense to me that I don't even really know how to critique it. "My particular data is exceedingly unlikely under the null so I reject the null" makes sense to me even though it is wrong (in the sense that the probability of type 1 error is intolerably high). What you're saying just seems downright garbled. Maybe you can try to explain the reasoning more carefully.

Comment: "My particular data is exceedingly unlikely under the null so I reject the null" is exactly what I'm saying. I'm furthermore adding that, since as it happens I *didn't* make a type 2 error (I did in fact reject the null), I don't think the high probability of a type 2 error is the real problem with the reasoning.

Comment: That's not what you were saying, because you said you only reject the null (conclude unfairness) when you get exactly 500 heads. If you're working off of "my particular data is exceedingly unlikely under the null so I reject the null" then you reject the null regardless of the data, which means you commit a type 1 error whenever the coin turns out to be fair. It also means you *never* commit a type 2 error because you *always* reject the null.

Comment: (Cont.) In this respect this "test" is not really a test at all, it is isomorphic to a "test" that spits out "I reject the null" without even inspecting the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65000/discussion-between-jack-m-and-ian).

Comment: Note that $3.05\times 10^{-151}$ is the probability of flipping a coin $500$ times and getting all $500$ flips to be heads.  The probability of exactly $500$ heads in $1000$ flips is about $.025225$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this test is "my particular data is very unlikely under the null hypothesis so I reject the null". The basic flaw in it is that *any* particular data is very unlikely under the null hypothesis, so you'll reject the null regardless of what data you actually get. This "paradox" is more dramatic with continuous distributions in which case the probability of observing *any* particular data is zero.

In the usual framework, this is taken care of by instead measuring the probability that data at least as favorable towards the alternative hypothesis as the given data would be seen under the null hypothesis. So in your situation you would consider the probability that $|X-500| \geq |x-500|$ where $X$ is the random number of heads in a flip and $x$ is the measured number of heads. The smaller this probability, the less reasonable your data makes the null appear.

In even more bland statistics jargon: a test like yours always commits a type 2 error if the null holds and never commits a type 1 error. Statisticians at a cultural level are more concerned about type 2 errors than type 1 errors, which in more colloquial language means they would rather say they don't know than say something false. You can set your priorities the other way around if you want, though you will need to be a bit less extreme about it to avoid creating weird situations like this one where you essentially deny any claim that anyone makes about anything.